# Little-Oh notation with index

Tags: probability, analysis, notation, computational-complexity

Currently I'm reading a paper in probability theory. Often, the author uses the little-oh-symbol, that I am not really familiar with, for example
$$
o_\varepsilon(n) \text{ for some } \varepsilon > 0 \text{ and } n\in\mathbb N.
$$
My intuition tells me that this means for a function $f_\varepsilon(n)\in o_\varepsilon(n)$ that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \frac{|f_\varepsilon(n)|}{n} = 0
$$
or something related.
Could you maybe tell me what you believe this means? I am especially uncertain with the index $\varepsilon$. For example with my "definition" that means for $f_\varepsilon(n) = \varepsilon$ and $g(n)=n$ that
$$
\frac{|f_\varepsilon(n)|}{g(n)} = \frac{\varepsilon}{n} \to 0
$$
for $\varepsilon \to 0$ (or should it be $n\to\infty$)?

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09744) is the link to the paper.

Comment: This may differ substantially author-to-author. One common meaning is that the rate of decay depends on $\epsilon$. If you give a reference to the paper it may be possible to help more.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I'm talking about this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09744) for example p. 9, equation (52).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this means that the unsubscripted version is true for any fixed value(s) of the subscripted variable(s). See, for example, p13 of [these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf) (this is for big-Oh, but the same concept applies).

Here $f_\epsilon(n)=o_\epsilon(n)$ would mean that if $\epsilon>0$ is kept fixed but $n\to \infty$ then $\frac{f_\epsilon(n)}{n}\to 0$. For example, $f_\epsilon(n)=\epsilon^{-1}\sqrt n$ satisfies this definition, but $f_\epsilon(n)=o(1)$ is not necessarily true if $\epsilon$ is allowed to depend on $n$.